Can i make a flexible function that can get * from different tables?
I am trying to create a function that can select from different tables in mysql
My Function
async function getOne(table, table_parameter, parameter) {
  const result = await pool.query(
    `SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?`,
    [table, table_parameter, parameter]
  )
}

Router:
companiesRouter.get('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  const id = request.params.id
  const company = await getOne('Company', 'companyID', id)
  response.send(company)
})

This ends up getting an error:

sql: "SELECT * FROM 'Company' WHERE 'companyID' = '1'",
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right

syntax to use near ''Company' WHERE 'companyID' = '1'' at line 1"
}

Is there any way for this to work?

You can't bind database objects (tables, columns views, procs, etc) as parameters. You have no choice but concatenate your objects dynamically into your sql statement, and then use parameterization/binding on the values for that extra protection. What this means though is that you'll be open to sql injection attacks. So you'll have to decide if this very dynamic SQL route you are headed is actually the best idea for doing whatever you are trying to do.

Most RDBMSs that I know of do not allow you to pass table names and columns names as parameters.

why do you want to do this? what problem are you trying to solve?

I agree with @JNevill, this is probably not a great idea. However, you can do this using ?? insead of ?.

It's always a good idea to read the docs. It's pretty clear: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers . The mysql2 library uses the same parser afaik.

Use the double question-mark syntax:
async function getOne(table, table_parameter, parameter) {
  const result = await pool.query(
    `SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?`,
    [table, table_parameter, parameter]
  );
}


Update dbquery formatting in function getOne as follows:
async function getOne(table, table_parameter, parameter) {
    const actual_query = mysql.format(
                             'SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?', 
                              [table, table_parameter, parameter]
                        ).replace(/'/g, '');

    console.log(actual_query);
    await pool.query({
            // sql: `SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE ${table_parameter} = ${parameter}`,
            sql: actual_query,
            timeout: 30000
        },
        (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('The solution is: ', results);
            return results;
        }
    );
 }

It will not show error and show result properly.

